# How can I find differences in two sets of objects?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

Given these two objects

```
var obj1 = [{ number: 23, team: 'Bulls', lastname: 'Jordan'}];
var obj2 = [{ number: 23, team: 'Bulls', lastname: 'Jordan'}, {number: 23, team: 'Cavaliers', lastname: 'James'}];
```

How can I iterate through both to return the differences, in this case

```
{number: 23, team: 'Cavaliers', lastname: 'James'}
```

I have set up something to the effect of

```
var difference = {};
if (obj2.length > obj1.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) {
        for (var j in obj2[i]) {
            for (var k in obj1[i]) {
                if (!(obj2[i][j] === obj1[i][k])) {
                    difference.push(obj2[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see why this is wrong, I just can't seem to figure out how to simultaneously loop through the first and second object's keys at the same time to compare them to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'changes'?

Comment: difference may be a better word choice. in the second one, there is a new object and I want that to be stored.

Comment: For that specific case you can just compare the lengths of the two arrays. The change is `obj2.slice(obj1.length);`. Presumably you mean something else.

Comment: awesome, very simple. thanks.

Comment: What you define as "change" or "difference" isn't entirely clear here. Presumably `difference` is supposed to be an array and you want to push on to it any object that exists in `obj2` but not in `obj1` (what about the reverse?) or any object in `obj2` that is different than in `obj1` which raises the question of how do you tell the difference between an object added and an object changed? Is one of the properties considered the primary key?

Comment: sorry I made an edit earlier when King Mob pointed out my error in nomenclature but forgot to update the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `obj2` is the same as `obj1` but with additional items pushed, then the set of changes is simply:

```
obj2.slice(obj1.length);
```

Comment: will this work if an array is spliced ...one item removed and replaced with another ?

Comment: No, this only works for the narrow constraints I mention.

Answer (score 2):

Your loops are very inefficient. I'm not sure where you're getting your data from, but if you're defining the structure yourself, I'd recommend changing the structure so that each 'object' is actually an object, not an array, and each 'player' object has a unique ID specific to that player.

So for instance, you might redefine the structure like this:

```
   obj1 = {};

   obj1.mJordan = new ConstructorForPlayer(23, "Bulls", "Jordan");
```

So that when you iterate through, you can use a for...in:

```
   for (var player in obj1){
     if (typeof obj2[player] !== 'undefined'){
       //some equality function here,
       //possibly defined in the prototype for the player object
     } else {
       changes.push(obj1[player]);
     }
   }
```

I'm also not sure how you're trying to track the changes or if putting the whole new object in your `changes` array is how you want it formatted, but I think your main problem is one of data structure.

Comment: yea the data is out of my hands and is in an array of object literals. being able to use the for in loop efficiently in my case would save so much time. thanks for the input. this looks like a good option when/if i can change the data

Answer (score 1):

fancy LINQ-style answer:

```
Array.prototype.any = function(obj){
    for(var item in this){
        var test = false;
        for(var name in this[item]){
            test = obj[name] === this[item][name];
        }
        if(test)
            return test;
    }
    return false;
};

//usage
obj2.any(obj1[0]);
```